# Coda output, joint quantile

Tags: bayesian, jags, coda

I am running a hierarchical model in JAGS. It is a piecewise constant survival regression model.

So I have 4 sets of regression coefficients and baseline hazard rates.

I would like to plot a mean curve and range using the mean and 95% highest density interval (HDI) of these parameters using the covariates from my data.

I have output from CODA, and it provides  marginal highest density intervals for each parameter. What would be the correct way to get the joint HDI for all parameters?